# How do you set the cursor position in SDL2?

Tags: c, window, sdl, sdl-2

I want to be able to change the position of the cursor over my SDL2 window. I can't find anything in the documentation. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: A few seconds of searching turns up `SDL_WarpMouseInWindow()` and `SDL_WarpMouseGlobal()`, which seem to do what you want...

Comment: @Dmitri Thanks! The unusual "WarpMouse" name is probably why I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `SDL_WarpMouseInWindow()` function, it sets the mouse position in the SDL Window.

Demonstration:

```
auto* WIN = SDL_CreateWindow("text", 0, 0, Width, Height, SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);
SDL_WarpMouseInWindow(WIN, 50, 50);/*sets mouse position to 50, 50 relative to the window */
```

Keep in mind, this invokes the `SDL_MOUSEMOTION` event so, if you're polling events, it will consider the change in mouse position as a mouse movement.

Here's a reference: https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_WarpMouseInWindow